# LINQ Hacer un contains con un string en una fecha

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

tengo un buscador donde el usuario mete un string y despues se hace un contains a cada columna en la base de datos.

```
dbContext.Usuario.Where(c=> 
   c.Nombre.Contains(filto) ||
   c.Apellido.Contains(filto) ||
   c.FechaNacimiento.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Contains(filto)
)
```

Pero al hacer **"Datetime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Contains(filtro)"** falla porque LINQ no lo puede traducir.
Y la busqueda puede ser '2002/12/28' o '01/07' o 'manolo' o '21' o cualquier cosa

Comment: que error te da? y porque le colocas el mismo filto a los 3 campos?

Comment: Y cómo sabes que lo escribe el usuario corresponde a qué columna de tu BD? Como manejas eso? O será que al escribir un valor como filtro, vas filtrando ese valor columna por columna? :O

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porque haces el filtro de esa manera, pero si quieres que te funciones deberías de hacer un .ToList() antes del Where() para que el filtrado se realice en memoria.

```
dbContext.Usuario
   .ToList()
   .Where(c=> 
   c.Nombre.Contains(filto) ||
   c.Apellido.Contains(filto) ||
   c.FechaNacimiento.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Contains(filto)
);
```

Ahora bien si quieres hacer algo más elegante te recomiendo que crees una clase con los parámetros que quieres filtra, esto mejorara el rendimiento.